# Searching through files for certain words... Being weird

Tags: python, python-3.x

I really don't know what's goin' on. I look up (in my search bar) "Hi" and it says 2 results found, if I looks up ANY OTHER WORD it just gives me a 500 error. Anyone?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cgi

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

searchHome = data.getvalue( 'search' )
result = "There was 0 results for search " + searchHome
total = 0
total = int(total)
with open('index.py') as f:
    for line in f:
        finded = line.find(searchHome)
        if finded != -1 and finded != 0:
            total += 1
            total = str(total)
            result = "There was " + total + " result(s) for search term: " + searchHome


print 'Content-type: text/html\n\r\n\r'
print result
```

Thanks for your help, Reefive / Sky Coleman. EDIT: Just fixed the code :D

More edits:
Ok, the error, I cannot find, I went through all the cPanel files, and more, looked at the help, etc. it just gives me a 500 error when I look up anything other than "Hi".

Comment: Could you post the searchbar side of the code?

Comment: 500 error means that exception was raised while executing script. Try to implement try-except block to catch that.

Comment: `total = 1; total = str(total); total += 1`, kaboom. Also this isn't Python3. Use `'There was {} result(s) for search term: {}'.format(total, searchHome)` to avoid having to convert strings.

Comment: No, it is Python3 but it mysteriously also supports Python2, And thanks for your help :D